# ¿Por qué no me está recibiendo la imagen en PHP enviada desde ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, formdata

Al enviar la imagen desde *ajax* y haciendo uso de *formData* en PHP no la lee, simplemente me muestra el mensaje de que no se recibió la imagen, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, ¿O es porque estoy usando *000webhost*?:

```js
function load() {
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('.input');
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: {number: "...", photo: formData},
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: (post) => {
      console.log(post);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="file" onchange="load()">
```

**Código PHP:**

```
if ($_FILES['photo']) {
  $file = $_FILES['photo'];
  if (getimagesize($file['tmp_name'])) {
    $imageData = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    $blobLink = 'data:' . $file['type'] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imageData);
    echo $blobLink;
  } else {
    echo "No es una imagen";
  }
} else {
  echo "No se recibió la imagen";
}
```

Comment: Prueba cambiar esto `formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);` por `formData.append('photo', fileInput.files[0]);`    ("file" por "photo")